# Dynamic Tab Navigator using static router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have 2 different tab navigators created. One navigator has 4 screens and other one has 5. Depending on the user type I need to populate those tabs after login.

My code is something like below,

```
import FourBottomNavigator from '../../navigation/Main/FourBottomNavigator';
import FiveBottomNavigator from '../../navigation/Main/FiveBottomNavigator';

class index extends Component {

    static router = FourBottomNavigator.router; //ISSUE COMES HERE. NEED TO MAKE THIS DYNAMIC

  render() {
        const { statusBarContent } = this.state;
        
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar
                    translucent
                    backgroundColor={Colors.TRANSPARENT}
                    barStyle={`${statusBarContent}-content`}
                />
            
                {this.props.userType === AppConstants.NEW_USER ? 
                    <FourBottomNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation} screenProps={this.props} />
                    : 
                    <FiveBottomNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation} screenProps={this.props} />
                }
                
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Problem is since I need to declare the `static router = FourBottomNavigator.router;` I cannot change it depending on the user type. How can I change the router dynamically?

If I can do something like this `static router = props.NewUser? FourBottomNavigator.router : FiveBottomNavigator.router;` but I can't because props cannot be accessed just like that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a tricky way to hide the one tab from using [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4069)

I have modified my `createBottomTabNavigator` following way. so now I can just use simply `FiveBottomNavigator` and depending on the user type. hide the other tab. so it will have just 4 items.

```
const RootBottomNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    TabHome: {
            screen: BookingContainer,
            navigationOptions: (props) => navigationOptions(props, ScreenConstants.bottomNav.HOME)
        },
    TabDelivery: {
        screen: (props) => {
            if(props.profileRole && props.profileRole.role === "ROLE_ADMIN"){
                return TimeContainer;
            }else{
                return null
            }
        },
        navigationOptions: (props) => {
            if(props.profileRole && props.profileRole.role === "ROLE_ADMIN"){
                return navigationOptions(props, ScreenConstants.bottomNav.TIME)
            }else{
                return {
                    tabBarOnPress: () => null,
                    tabBarButton: () => null,
                    tabBarButtonComponent: () => null,
                    tabBarLabel: () => null,
                }
            }
            
        }
    },
    TabMeeting {
        screen: MeetingContainer,
        navigationOptions: (props) => navigationOptions(props, ScreenConstants.bottomNav.MEETING)
    },
);
```